# useState does not updates when useSelector is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, use-state

I think it is weird, but I do not understand why useState does not being set to new value. When looking at the picture we could see useSelector is updated and it should update useState aswell.
I'm talking about `flatData` state. From what I understand ``` flatData`` should get ``` currentColiving`data at the first render. Then, whenever`currentColiving`is updated -`flatData``` should be updated. However, the picture says different story.
Here is the code:

```
function FlatInformation() {
  const currentColiving = useSelector(selectCurrentColiving);
  const [imageFiles, setImageFiles] = useState([]);
  const [flatData, setFlatData] = useState({
    name: currentColiving?.title || "",
    description: currentColiving?.description || "",
    photos: currentColiving?.imageUrl || [],
    amenities: currentColiving?.amenities || [],
  });
  // Boolean whether a person can edit coliving settings or not.
  const flatSettingsEditMode = useSelector(selectIsInSettingsEditMode);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentColiving) {
      console.log(flatData, 'flatData-begin');
      setFlatData((prevState) => ({
        name: currentColiving.title,
        description: currentColiving.description,
        photos: currentColiving.imageUrl,
        amenities: currentColiving.amenities,
      }));
      console.log(currentColiving);
      console.log(flatData, 'Flatdata-end');
    }
  }, [currentColiving]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(flatData, "flatData");
  }, [flatData]);
return (
<div>ommited</div>)

}
```

Pictures:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: Also, it looks like `currentColiving` is an array, but you're accessing properties on it like it's an object.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Yuup you are totally correct. Everything now is working properly. I updated ```currentColiving``` with ```.filter()```, so it returned me an array, but I need only ```[0]```. Thank you :)